# How to make a modal window in HTML5 and CSS3 popup automatically

Tags: html, css, modal-dialog

I found some code online allowing me to create and design a modal window for visitors to sign up to our newsletter, but i want this modal window to popup automatically when the index page is opened. So far i have only been able to find modal windows that rely upon the user clicking on a hyperlink. Is there a function i can use to automatically open the modal window or a way to automatically load a hyperlink.

This is the link i used to create my modal window. [Link](http://designwebsiteblog.com/design/web-design/creating-a-modal-window-with-html5-css3.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [**keyframe animations**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/@keyframes) ([**support**](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-animation)). Something like:

```
.modalDialog {
   /* other styles */
   animation: showup .5s;
}
@keyframes showup { to { opacity: 1; } }
```

Be careful with `pointer-events` though. They won't work in any version of IE or Opera - [see **support for pointer-events in CSS**](http://caniuse.com/#feat=pointer-events).

A really simple [demo](http://dabblet.com/gist/4572783) I just did.

Comment: what did u exactly achieve with the negative margin?

Answer (score 0):

Try this it worked for me

```
<script type="text/javascript">    
    $(function () {    
        $("#dialog").dialog({    
            modal: true,    
            autoOpen: false,
            title: "jQuery Dialog",    
            width: 300,    
            height: 150    
        });    
        $("#btnShow").click(function () {    
            $('#dialog').dialog('open');    
        });    
    });    
</script>
```

Reference: [Open-Show-jQuery-UI-Dialog-Modal-Popup-on-Button-Click](https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Open-Show-jQuery-UI-Dialog-Modal-Popup-on-Button-Click.aspx)

Answer (score -1):

You can always enclose the link to modal window in a span or div. then on page load using jquery use the .click() function to autoload it.