# How to show div on page load?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I am referring to following link:

http://netdna.webdesignerdepot.com/uploads7/creating-a-modal-window-with-html5-and-css3/demo.html

Here, the div ( modal window ) is loaded after clicking on the link.
I am trying to get rid of that link and open that modal on page load.

My code is as follows:
Everything is same except I have added scripts and removed the link

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Modal Window</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        .modalDialog
        {
            position: fixed;
            font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
            top: 0;
            right: 0;
            bottom: 0;
            left: 0;
            background: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
            z-index: 99999;
            opacity: 0;
            -webkit-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
            -moz-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
            transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
            pointer-events: none;
        }
        .modalDialog:target
        {
            opacity: 1;
            pointer-events: auto;
        }
        .modalDialog > div
        {
            width: 400px;
            position: relative;
            margin: 10% auto;
            padding: 5px 20px 13px 20px;
            border-radius: 10px;
            background: #fff;
            background: -moz-linear-gradient(#fff, #999);
            background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#fff, #999);
            background: -o-linear-gradient(#fff, #999);
        }
        .close
        {
            background: #606061;
            color: #FFFFFF;
            line-height: 25px;
            position: absolute;
            right: -12px;
            text-align: center;
            top: -10px;
            width: 24px;
            text-decoration: none;
            font-weight: bold;
            -webkit-border-radius: 12px;
            -moz-border-radius: 12px;
            border-radius: 12px;
            -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
            -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
            box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
        }
        .close:hover
        {
            background: #00d9ff;
        }
    </style>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#openModal").show();
        });
    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <div id="openModal" class="modalDialog">
        <div>
            <a href="#close" title="Close" class="close">X</a>
            <h2>
                Modal Box</h2>
            <p>
                This is a sample modal box that can be created using the powers of CSS3.</p>
            <p>
                You could do a lot of things here like have a pop-up ad that shows when your website
                loads, or create a login/register form for users.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Similar question is asked here: [How to Auto Popup a CSS3 Modal Window When Page Loads?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16126788/how-to-auto-popup-a-css3-modal-window-when-page-loads)

But its not helping.

I have also tried following scripts without any luck:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#openModal").click();
});


$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".modalDialog").show();
});
```

I must be doing something wrong here.

Any ideas?

Comment: try $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#openModal").trigger('click');
});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `.show()` is not changing the opacity of `$("#openModal")`

do

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    // the first arg is duration of the effect, second is the opacity to end at
    $("#openModal").fadeTo(500, 1);
});
```

[Check out the Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zPgj8/1/)

As the OP pointed out the "dismiss Model Button" was not working

[Updated Fiddle Demostrating a working dismiss button](http://jsfiddle.net/zPgj8/13/)

Comment: most of the chances are is that because of the modal is not initialized, but only shown.

Comment: I tried increasing the duration (fadeTo) as well. But no luck !!

Comment: it is in milliseconds, so increase it to 1000 and you should notice the difference.

Comment: @Icarus3, please checkout the new fiddle link

Answer (score 0):

as @Charaf jra suggested,
you should trigger the click with:

```
$(document).ready(function() { $("#openModal").trigger('click'); });
```

on the other hand,
most of the chances are you can trigger it onload with:

```
$(document).ready(function() { $(".modalDialog").modal() }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(window).load(function(event){
    $(".modalDialog").show();
})
```

Comment: bad practice to use `setTimeout` you should get rid of it @harsha, unless you really must use it.

Comment: @Dementic : Okay , but would you let me know why it's a bad practice ? I wish to know.

Comment: `setTimeout` does not guarantee that "ANY" object is loaded, or is there, also, it does not guarantee any function or anything is there.
You should make checks to see if its there. *EDIT* and if you already validate those are there, then there is no reason to use `setTimeout` is there?

Answer (score 0):

To trigger click event , use `trigger()`  :

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $("#openModal").trigger('click'); 
});
```

Answer (score -2):

You have opacity: 0; for .modalDialog. In this case you need to use fadeTo instead of show.

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".modalDialog").fadeTo(1,1);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Copying someone else's answer is a no no.
Welcome to SO.