# Triggering popup on load using CSS3

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have looked for answer in every thread from past and I cannot find it. I have problem with triggering popup. I used some online tutorials to make popup window. I successfully made it, but only way to trigger it is on click. Like this:

`<a href="#openModal">Open Modal</a>
<div id="openModal" class="modalDialog">`

I checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16126788/how-to-auto-popup-a-css3-modal-window-when-page-loads) thread but it's not working for me.

Comment: So do you want a [CSS3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13630229) or a jQuery solution? Could you share your code you tried in your requested language?

Answer (score 0):

So I did it by simply redirecting user to URL that is triggering popup.

HTML:

`<body onload="Redirect()">`

JavaScript:

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
    function Redirect() {
               window.location="My_url/index.html#openModal";
            }
      </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

### Hacky CSS solution

If you used the [`:target` trick](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17257848/1494454) to create a CSS only trigger, than just swap the regular and the target rule, so the pop-up will render on load as everything else and the close button will hide the pop-up:

```css
#close:target {
   display: none;
}

/*Just for style*/
#close {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="close">
    <a href="#close">Close (X)</a>
    <p>We hate pop-ups!</p>
</div>
```

### Standar JavaScript solution

Otherwise if you use JavaScript to execute a display code on load, then why not to do it all in JavaScript? You are already not "CSS only":

```js
window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById('popup').style.display = 'block';
};

document.getElementById('close').addEventListener('click', function () {
    document.getElementById('popup').style.display = 'none';
});
```

```css
#popup {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="popup">
    <a href="#c" id="close">Close (X)</a>
    <p>We hate pop-ups!</p>
</div>
```

Comment: I didn't had time to test your solution because I made it work with solution I posted earlier. But thank you very much on your time, maybe someone else will find this useful. :)